# AndroidQ : How to access Dynamic Depth Format

Tags: android-camera2, android-10.0

Android Q features blogs mentions about a new feature Dynamic Depth Format.

> Starting in Android Q, apps can request a Dynamic Depth image which >consists of a JPEG, XMP metadata related to depth related elements, >and a depth and confidence map embedded in the same file on devices >that advertise support.

But i am not able to find this file format . I  tried parsing the jpeg for any metadata associated but i could not place the file. Has anyone tried accessing the file?

Comment: Have you seen [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/Dynamic-depth-v1.0.pdf)?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @gomathi_meena Not yet. Will let you know if i stumble upon something worthwhile

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494608/how-to-get-depth-map-in-android-q/63660506#63660506

Comment: Refer to answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957619/android-q-get-depth-map-from-portrait-mode-photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957619/android-q-get-depth-map-from-portrait-mode-photos) for parsing depthmap.