# Real-time scene's depth map using smartphone camera and depth sensor

Tags: android, 3d, computer-vision, arcore

I am trying to get the depth map of a scene **in real time for video application** using a smartphone. In order to do that I need to access the depth sensor of the phone or use the dual cameras as stereo camera. Any ideas how to do that using Android SDK or other API please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scene's depth map using smartphone camers or depth sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339086/scenes-depth-map-using-smartphone-camers-or-depth-sensor)

Comment: It is my first question(closed). I submited a new question because I need a solution that works in real time.@PeterO.

Comment: Does the following help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494608/how-to-get-depth-map-in-android-q  If not, edit your question to explain why not.